# closing the html page and return to the initial display

Tags: html

I am opening an html page using `location.assign()`. This page will be displayed in a section `div` inside index.html. I would like a button that can go back to the content before the `location.assign` link was clicked. I have try the following but the result is not what I expected.

1. `<span class="" onclick="window.history.back()">&times;</span>` - (close the whole page)
2. `<button onclick="history.go(-1)">Back</button>` - (same as above)
3. `<a href="http://www.MymainPage.com" target="_parent" class="">×</a>` - (Restart the whole page)

The latter is my current solution as for now but it is not exactly what I want. What I need is a button to close the assigned html page and leave it as initially. (before the location.assigned() was triggered.)

Thank in advance!!

Comment: Have you considered opening the link in a new tab?

Comment: If it is possible to have it in the same location/display that would be great. Having it in a new tab is less suitable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

What a simple thing!! I forgot that the content in the section is an Iframe and I am using src="MyURL" to display it. Thus, the solution for the above is creating a link that direct back to the iframe. In my case:

```
<a href="MyURL" target="_self"><span class="" onclick="">&times;</span></a>
```

Hours spent just for this. Arghhhh!!